# What distributions are there that package Plasma Bigscreen?

Tags: kde, distribution-choice, distributions, plasma

I recently found out about [Plasma Bigscreen](https://plasma-bigscreen.org/), but I can't really find any distributions that package it. The only thing I find is a prebuilt image for the Raspberry Pi 4, but I would like something that works on a regular x86_64 PC (without QEMU of course). What distributions are there that package Plasma Bigscreen so that it can be used on a regular PC?

Comment: What is it? link please.

Comment: To date, *and as far as I know*, there's only a [Pi option](https://plasma-bigscreen.org/#download-jumpto). Unless you're prepared to do the work yourself, you'll have to wait and see if folks pick it up and package it for other distros.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor I'm pretty sure they're referring to [this](https://plasma-bigscreen.org/). It made the rounds on the FOSS type news sites earlier this year. It looks rather interesting. It hasn't been around for very long, so I'm not sure how much traction it's going to get.

Comment: Yes, KGIII is right. I added the link to my question.